# Работа со слайсами

Tags: golang

Есть достаточно простой кусок кода (см. [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BcdOCvARvWN)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func foo(i int, b []int) {
    fmt.Println(i, b)
}

func main() {
    a := []int{0, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99}
    for i, _ := range a {
        if i%2 == 0 {
            foo(i, append(a[:i], a[i+1:]...))
        }
    }
}
```

Хотелось получить результат работы:

```
0 [11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99]
2 [ 0 11 33 44 55 66 77 88 99]
4 [ 0 11 22 33 55 66 77 88 99]
6 [ 0 11 22 33 44 55 77 88 99]
8 [ 0 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 99]
```

А получается:

```
0 [11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99]
2 [11 22 44 55 66 77 88 99 99]
4 [11 22 44 55 77 88 99 99 99]
6 [11 22 44 55 77 88 99 99 99]
8 [11 22 44 55 77 88 99 99 99]
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: P.S. если вместо `append` использовать функцию:
`func append_(a []int, b ...int) (c []int) {
 return append(append(c, a...), b...)
}` То все работает как нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы переписываете один и тот же слайс.

Вот отличная статья на эту тему: https://habr.com/company/mailru/blog/314804/#43

Вот посмотрите ваш код https://play.golang.org/p/qcf6aFblXIx

Вам нужно что-то вроде: https://play.golang.org/p/EOk8ijSuG9s

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func foo(i int, b []int) {
    fmt.Println(i, b)
}

func main() {
    a := []int{0, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99}
    for i, _ := range a {

        // b полная копия a и мы никогда не меняем а
        b := make([]int, len(a))
        copy(b, a)

        if i%2 == 0 {
            fmt.Println(b[:i], b[i+1:])
            foo(i, append(b[:i], b[i+1:]...))
            fmt.Println(a)
            fmt.Println()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто из документации на append не очень понятно как  и чего. Например в случае https://play.golang.org/p/v8GPvINl6YY еще интереснее картина получается :-)

Comment: согласен это точно готча...